# Hide all divs having a certain class using Prototype?

Tags: html, prototypejs

How can I hide all divs having the class *myclass* using Prototype? I guess something like $$('myclass') and foreach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$$("div.myclass").each(Element.hide);
```